# Convert a bash variable to JSON array and JSON object using jq

Tags: json, type-conversion, jq

I have a variable, X, in a bash script that has a value like `asw|uduu|sssdd`. How can I convert it to a JSON array using jq?

A second variable, Y, has a value like `A:1|B:1|C:1`. How can I convert it to a JSON object using jq?

Please help me solve these conversion tasks.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'asw|uduu|sssdd' | jq -Rc 'split("|")'
```

produces:
    ["asw","uduu","sssdd"]

The "-c" option is inessential here - it just compacts the output.

```
echo 'A:1|B:1|C:1' |
 jq -Rc 'split("|") | map( split(":") | {(.[0]): .[1]} ) | add'
```

produces: {"A":"1","B":"1","C":"1"}

To understand how the last one works, run the leftmost part of the pipeline first, and then add successive parts.